# appropriateness of 'the latter' in this sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, pronouns

This is from [a webpage](https://ekja.org/journal/view.php?number=8734).

> The performance of bilateral intracluster blocks on cadavers resulted
> in 25% of specimens having subperineural ink on histologic
> examination, with 90% of **the latter** being intrafascicular with
> evidence of axonal distortion or damage.

'The latter' seems to refer to 25% of specimens but I think it is better to just change 'the latter' to 'them'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: The proper solution when there are ambiguities in a result cited from another paper, is to look at the other paper.  In this case you can find the exact result in https://www.bjanaesthesia.org/article/S0007-0912(19)30142-4/fulltext  You should do this because what you quote doesn't make sense to you.  You can only speak of "the latter" when you have identified mentioned two groups. The original is clear.  In 21 cadavers,  providing 41 injections sites,   10 showed sup-perineural ink, and all but one of those 10 showed axonal damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think you are right to say "the latter" refers to the 25% of specimens, and yes, I think you can change it to "them".

This is because when the text says "being intrafascicular with evidence of axonal distortion or damage", it is quite obvious it is pointing to the specimens, so I think using "them" should be fine.